# Formula to determine whether a value is within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My company is eligible to receive additional money if I receive a product within a certain time period. As long as F2 (Date Rec'd) falls on or between A2 and B2 (The Eligible Dates), and G2 (my model) matches C2 (eligible model), I am eligible to receive a certain $$ amount (D2). I would like that to show up in H2.

What I received...
In F2-F900, I have a date in which a product was received.
In G2-G900, I have the specific model # that was received.

What the program allows...
In A2-A250, I have a start date
In B2-B250, I have a end date
In C2-C250, I have a model #
In D2-D250, I have a $$ amount that I am eligible for

If I wasn't worrying about the dates, I would use Vlookup.

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$C$2:$D$950,2,FALSE)
```

...however, I don't know what to enter to make it meet more criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data setup looks something like this:

[image: Sample data setup]

Then in cell H2 and copied down is this formula (adjust ranges to suit):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$4<=F2)*($B$2:$B$4>=F2)*($C$2:$C$4=G2),),0)),"")
```